# Swift NSWindow shows up and disappears immediately

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nswindow

I'm a complete beginner to Swift, so this may be a silly question, but I can't figure out how this works...

I have a view with a button inside which calls the following code:

```
let window = NSWindow()
window.center()
window.title = "test"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

When I click the button the window opens just for a moment and disappears a few milliseconds later.

Can anyone help me with that? It seems I have a quite serious misunderstanding about views in Cocoa ;-)

Thanks
Tom

Comment: In my button action. And of course that's wrong. Thank you very much for your quick response!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are creating and 'storing' the `NSWindow` in your button action function. That means that as soon as that button action is done, the `NSWindow` will go *out of context*, and be released and thus disappear.

This is how the memory management in Swift works: as soon as nobody *owns* an object anymore, it will be released.

What you should do is put your window in an instance variable. Like for example:

```
class YourViewController: NSViewController {
    private var window: NSWindow!

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        window = NSWindow()
        window.center()
        window.title = "test"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)    
    }
}
```

The hint about `makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)` makes no difference. Passing either `nil` or `self` is fine. But latter, how you did it originaly, makes more sense.