# NSWindow just closes by itself

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I made a macos app that shows a nswindow having a webview in the view controller.

The source is

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

     func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let company_no = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "company_no")
        if(company_no == nil){

        let storyboard: NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LoginForm") as? NSWindowController
        let window:NSWindow = windowController!.window!
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        return
        }

     }
}
```

This works perfectly in macos 10.12 above. But the window closes by itself in os below especially in yosemite and el capitan... What is the problem with the source? I have check other similar questions answered... But none of it helped me.

Comment: move your window declaration out of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method

Comment: @LeoDabus I have tried let storyboard: NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LoginForm") as? NSWindowController
            windowController?.showWindow(nil) but also doesn't work

Comment: `var window: NSWindow!`
     `func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {` `window = windowController!.window!`

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm new to ios programming...is there a reason to move the declaration outside of the function??

Comment: You need to keep a reference of your window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift NSWindow shows up and disappears immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399693/swift-nswindow-shows-up-and-disappears-immediately)